# How to have reply comment to the comment box in blog site Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

I have a blog site in Sharepoint 2010, by default we have a option for comment on the blog, now I need to have reply to the comment posted on blog. Is there any out of box feature to to achieve this.

Comment: in 2010 there is no OOTB feature available for this.

Comment: Thanks for the Reply Amit, Any idea of how to achieve this via coding

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to create a custom site definition using the blog site as your starting point. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms454677(v=office.14).aspx
Then you'd have to override the Comments list functionality to add your own behavior. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff728096(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: My pleasure and good luck!