# How to add reply to the comment for blog site post on SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, blog, comments

Is there a way to reply to a comment on SharePoint Online blog post through customization? I don't think there is any OOB option available.

I don't have experience in creating remote event receivers or any custom jobs. Please provide a detailed description.

Comment: are you asking for blog site collection or blog feature under delve?

Comment: I created a site using Blog template. For Post list, the comment filed is by default. I want to add reply to a comment feature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comments section on each post is a list view web part pulling from the Comments list. In order to get the reply feature, we need to create a custom Comments web part using HTML, and JavaScript.

Here is my analysis to finish this customization

**New Column in Comments List**

The reply is also a comment to another comment on a post. But it requires to know the parent comment. For this, we are adding a new column to the comments list.

> Field Name = Parent Comment ID, Field Type = Number

**JavaScript function to get posts, comment on a post and reply on a comment**

```
//get comments
funciton getComments(postID) {
    var requestUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "_api/web/Lists/getByTitle('Comments')/Items?$filter=PostTitleId eq " + postID;
    $.ajax({
            url: requestUrl,
            method: "GET",          
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
            success: function (data) {
                bindComments(data.d.results);               
            },
            error: function (data) {
                fail(data);
            }
        }); 
}
//bind comments
function bindComments(comments) {
    var container = $("#comments-container ul");
    foreach(var comment in comments) {
        container.append("<li comment-id='comment.Id' post-id='comment.PostTitleId'>\
                            <span>" + comment.Title  + "</span> \
                            <span>" + comment.Author.Title + "</span>\
                            <a href='javascript:' class='reply-comment'> \                          
                        </li>");

    }

    $(".reply-comment").on("click", function()) {
        $(this).closest("li").append("<div>\
                                        <input type='textbox'><input type='button' value='Reply' id='btnReply'>\
                                    </div>");

    }
    $("#btnReply").on("click", function(){
        var postId=$(this).closest("li").attr("post-id");
        var parentCommentId=$(this).closest("li").attr("comment-id");
        var comment = $(this).prev("input[type=text]").val();
        //Insert to Comments list using REST Api call
        var listItem = { Title: "your reply title", 
                        PostTitleId: postId, 
                        Body: comment, 
                        ParentCommentId: parentCommentId}; 
    });
}

//post a comment or reply
function postComment(comment) {

        var item = {
            "__metadata": { "type": "SP.Data.CommentsListItem" }
        };

        $.extend(item, comment);

        $.ajax({
            url: webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('" + listName + "')/items",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            data: JSON.stringify(item),
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert('Success');
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert('fail')
            }
        });

}

$(document).ready(function(){
    var postId = //get post id from url;
    $("#btnPostComment").ready(function() {
        var comment = $("#txtComment").val();       
        var listItem = { Title: "your reply title", 
                        PostTitleId: postId, 
                        Body: comment, 
                        ParentCommentId: 0};
        postComment(comment);
    });
    getComments(postId);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="comments-container">
    <ul></ul>
    <div id="comment-box-container">
        <input type="text" id="txtComment">
        <input type="button" value="POST" id="btnPostComment">
    </div>
</div>
```

**Use the component**

1. You can remove the old comments web part on the Post.aspx page
2. You can add this component to the content editor web part. (Keep everything in a JavaScript and HTML files then refer in the content editor web part)

This is only prototype to build your reply feature along with exisiting features.

I feel this will give flexibity to extend your blog post even further.

Comment: Thanks so much @Venkat Konjeti. I really appreciate your assistance. I will apply this and will reach you back.

Answer (score 2):

Out of the box, I don't think this is not an option in SharePoint; therefore, it requires some custom work to be done.

However, I believe that a [similar question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/173721/how-to-have-reply-comment-to-the-comment-box-in-blog-site-sharepoint-2010) has already been asked on here.

Comment: Hello Caldwell. I appreciate your reply. But that doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

One such requirement was to have the ability to comment and reply on the comments on the news articles. Obviously, there was no out-of-the-box page layout in SharePoint online that gives this feature, so we had to do something custom.

```
<div class="container">  
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">  
        <hr> <label for="comment">Enter Comments:</label> <textarea class="form-control " rows="3" id="comment"></textarea> <a href="" ID="btn_CommentsSave" class="cbs-Line1Link ms-noWrap ms-displayBlock" data-bind="click: createListItem">  
<span> <i class="ms-Icon ms-Icon--post"></i> Post Comment</span>  
</a></div>  
</div>  
<div class="container">  
    <div class="row">  
        <div class="col-md-8">  
            <h2 class="page-header"><span data-bind="text: commentsCount"></span> Comments</h2>  
            <hr>  
            <section class="comment-list">  
                <!-- First Comment -->  
                <div class="row" data-bind="foreach: commentsfromUsers" style="padding: 5px !important">  
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 hidden-xs" style="padding: 5px !important">  
                        <figure class="thumbnail"> <img class="img-responsive" data-bind="attr:{src: photo}" />  
                            <figcaption class="text-center" data-bind="text: userName"></figcaption>  
                        </figure>  
                    </div> 
<div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10">  
                        <div class="panel panel-default arrow left">  
                            <div class="panel-body" style="border:thin #C0C0C0 solid !important;">  
                                <header class="text-left"> <a><i class="ms-Icon ms-Icon--person" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> <span data-bind="text: userName"> </span> <a><i class="ms-Icon ms-Icon--event" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> <time datetime="16-12-2014 01:05" data-bind="text: Created"></time> </header>  
                                <div class="comment-post" data-bind="text: Comments"></div>  
                                <div class="text-right" align="right"><span data-bind="text: repliesCount"></span> reply(s) <a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.ShowHideItems"><i class="ms-Icon ms-Icon--reply"></i> Reply</a></div>  
                            </div>  
                        </div>  
                    </div>  
                    <div class="row" data-bind="attr:{id: 'divReply'+Id}" style="display:none !important;padding: 5px !important;" align="right">  
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-offset-0 hidden-xs">  
                            <div class="form-group col-md-8"> <textarea class="form-control " rows="3" data-bind="attr:{id: 'addReply'+Id}"></textarea> <a ID="btn_addReplySave" href="" data-bind="click: $root.createReplyListItem">  
<i class="ms-Icon ms-Icon--post"></i> Post Reply  
</a></div>  
                        </div>  
                    </div>  
                    <div class="row"></div>  
                    <!-- Second Comment Reply -->  
                    <div data-bind="foreach: replies ">  
                        <div class="row">  
                            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-0 hidden-xs">  
                                <figure class="thumbnail"> <img class="img-responsive" data-bind="attr:{src: photo}" />  
                                    <figcaption class="text-center" data-bind="text: userName"></figcaption>  
                                </figure>  
                            </div>  
                            <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8">  
                                <div class="panel panel-default arrow left">  
                                    <div class="panel-heading right"> Reply</div>  
                                    <div class="panel-body" style="border:thin #C0C0C0 solid !important;">  
                                        <header class="text-left"> <a><i class="ms-Icon ms-Icon--person" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> <span data-bind="text: userName"></span> <a><i class="ms-Icon ms-Icon--event" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> <time datetime="16-12-2014 01:05" data-bind="text: Created"> </time> </header>  
                                        <div class="comment-post" data-bind="text: reply"></div>  
                                    </div>  
                                </div>  
                            </div>  
                        </div>  
                    </div>  
                </div>  
            </section>  
        </div>  
    </div>  
</div>  `

The following JavaScript was added to the page layout.

    var siteCollectionURL = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;  
var pageurl = window.location.href.replace("%20", "").replace("%27", "").replace(/[&$%‘’']/g, "");  

function ShowHideItems() {  
    document.getElementById('replyToComments').style.display = 'block';  
}  
var Comment = function(comment, Id, Created, CreatedById, replies) {  
    this.Comments = comment;  
    this.Id = Id;  
    var num = parseInt(Created.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ""));  
    var date = new Date(num);  
    this.Created = date.toLocaleString();  
    this.CreatedById = CreatedById;  
    this.replies = ko.observableArray(replies);  
    this.photo = ko.observable();  
    this.userName = ko.observable();  
    this.repliesCount = ko.observable(replies.length);  
    var self = this;  
    $.ajax({  
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + '/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/UserInformationList?$filter=Id%20eq%20' + CreatedById,  
        method: "GET",  
        headers: {  
            "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"  
        },  
        success: function(data) {  
            self.photo("https://<TenantURL>/_layouts/15/userphoto.aspx?size=S&accountname=" + data.d.results[0].WorkEmail.toString());  
            self.userName(data.d.results[0].Name);  
        },  
        error: function(data) {  
            alert('Error' + data.error);  
        }  
    });  
}  
var Reply = function(reply, Id, ParentId, Created, CreatedById) {  
    this.reply = reply;  
    this.Id = Id;  
    this.ParentId = ParentId;  
    var num = parseInt(Created.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ""));  
    var date = new Date(num);  
    this.Created = date.toLocaleString();  
    this.CreatedById = CreatedById;  
    this.photo = ko.observable();  
    this.userName = ko.observable();  
    var self = this;  
    $.ajax({  
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + '/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/UserInformationList?$filter=Id%20eq%20' + CreatedById,  
        method: "GET",  
        headers: {  
            "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"  
        },  
        success: function(data) {  
            self.photo("https://<TenantURL>/_layouts/15/userphoto.aspx?size=S&accountname=" + data.d.results[0].WorkEmail.toString());  
            self.userName(data.d.results[0].Name);  
        },  
        error: function(data) {  
            alert('Error' + data.error);  
        }  
    });  
}  

function getReplies(ID) {  
    var commentsurl = siteCollectionURL + '/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Replies?$filter=%20ParentID%20eq%20%27' + ID + '%27';  
    var replies = new Array();  
    $.ajax({  
        url: siteCollectionURL + '/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Replies?$filter=%20ParentID%20eq%20%27' + ID + '%27',  
        method: "GET",  
        headers: {  
            "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"  
        },  
        success: function(data2) {  
            for (var i = 0; i < data2.d.results.length; i++) {  
                replies.push(new Reply(data2.d.results[i].Reply, data2.d.results[i].Id, ID, data2.d.results[i].Created, data2.d.results[i].CreatedById));  
            }  
        },  
        error: function(data2) {  
            replies = null;  
        },  
        async: false  
    });  
    return replies;  
}  

function ClearFields() {  
    document.getElementById('comment').value = "";  
}  

function getParameterByName(name, url) {  
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;  
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");  
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),  
        results = regex.exec(url);  
    if (!results) return null;  
    if (!results[2]) return '';  
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));  
}  

function CommentReplyViewModel() {  
    var self = this;  
    self.userID = ko.observable();  
    self.commentsfromUsers = ko.observableArray();  
    self.RepliesfromUsers = ko.observableArray();  
    self.commentsCount = ko.observable();  
    self.ShowHideItems = function(data) {  
        $('#divReply' + data.Id).slideToggle();  
    }  
    self.getCommentsListItem = function() {  
        var commentsurl = siteCollectionURL + '/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Comments?$filter=%20Title%20eq%20%27' + pageurl + '%27';  
        $.ajax({  
            url: siteCollectionURL + '/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Comments?$filter=%20Title%20eq%20%27' + pageurl + '%27',  
            method: "GET",  
            headers: {  
                "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"  
            },  
            success: function(data2) {  
                self.commentsfromUsers.removeAll();  
                self.commentsCount(data2.d.results.length);  
                for (var i = 0; i < span data - mce - type = "bookmark"  
                    id = "mce_SELREST_start"  
                    data - mce - style = "overflow:hidden;line-height:0"  
                    style = "overflow:hidden;line-height:0" > < /span><span data-mce-type="bookmark" id="mce_SELREST_start" data-mce-style="overflow:hidden;line-height:0" style="overflow:hidden;line-height:0" ></span > < data2.d.results.length; i++) {  
                    self.commentsfromUsers.push(new Comment(data2.d.results[i].Comments, data2.d.results[i].Id, data2.d.results[i].Created, data2.d.results[i].CreatedById, getReplies(data2.d.results[i].Id)));  
                }  
            },  
            error: function(data2) {  
                alert('Error' + data.error);  
            }  
        });  
    }  
    self.createListItem = function() {  
        var commentsValue = document.getElementById('comment').value;  
        var url = siteCollectionURL + "/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Comments";  
        var Comments = {  
            Comments: commentsValue,  
            SiteURL: pageurl,  
            Title: pageurl  
        };  
        var body = JSON.stringify(Comments);  
        $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            url: url,  
            contentType: 'application/json',  
            processData: false,  
            data: body,  
            success: function() {  
                alert('Comments Saved Successfully.');  
                document.getElementById('comment').value = "";  
                self.getCommentsListItem();  
            }  
        });  
    }  
    self.createReplyListItem = function(data) {  
        var RepliesValue = document.getElementById('addReply' + data.Id).value;  
        var pageurl = window.location.href;  
        var allReplies;  
        var url = siteCollectionURL + "/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Replies";  
        var Replies = {  
            Reply: RepliesValue,  
            ParentID: data.Id.toString(),  
            Title: pageurl  
        };  
        var body = JSON.stringify(Replies);  
        $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            url: url,  
            contentType: 'application/json',  
            processData: false,  
            data: body,  
            success: function() {  
                alert('Reply Saved Successfully.');  
                document.getElementById('addReply' + data.Id).value = "";  
                $('#divReply' + data.Id).slideToggle();  
                allReplies = getReplies(data.Id);  
                data.replies(allReplies);  
                data.repliesCount(allReplies.length);  
            },  
            error: function(error) {  
                alert(error.error);  
            },  
            async: false  
        });  
    }  
    $.ajax({  
        url: url,  
        method: "GET",  
        headers: {  
            "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"  
        },  
        success: function(data) {  
            self.getCommentsListItem();  
        },  
        error: function(data) {  
            alert(data.error);  
        }  
    });  
}  
$(document).ready(function() {  
    ko.applyBindings(new CommentReplyViewModel());  
});
```

Check-In and publish the page layout as a major version.

Comment: How can I remove the old comments web part on the Post.aspx page ?